# Get data from Firebase after is initialized

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get data from db from my main component only after I am connected to Firebase

```
this.AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
```

This is in my app.module. I want to get data from db after Firebase is initialized.
The problem is that I try to get my user data from db but I get error first time I tried because my app is not connected to firebase. When I refresh the page there is no problem because is already connected.

Here is my app.module.ts

```
 @NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
HomeComponent,
CategorieComponent,
SignComponent,
TopicComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
HttpModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
AngularFireDatabaseModule, // imports firebase/database, only needed 
for database features
AngularFireAuthModule // imports firebase/auth, only needed for auth 
features
],
providers: [SharedService, UsersService],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-- EDIT --**
It's not a Firebase issue, it's a timing problem. After starting your app, Firebase has to read and decrypt the user-token from the localstorage. Until this has finished, currentUser is undefined and you will get an error if you try to access properties like email or uid.

I recommend you to use Observables, to track changes. Otherwise you will receive the same problems on login and logout. This can look like the following:

**userService.ts**

```
...
public authInfo = new BehaviorSubject<UserInfo>(undefined);
authInfo$ = this.authInfo.asObservable();

constructor(private fbAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
   this.fbAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authInfo => this.authInfo.next(authInfo));
}
...
```

**component.ts**

```
...
authInfo$: Observable<UserInfo>;

constructor(private userService: UserService) {
   this.authInfo$ = this.authService.authInfo$;
}
...
```

**component.html**

```
...
<div>{{ (authInfo$ | async)?.email }}</div>
...
```

The async-pipe manages the subscription of the observable, and the elvis-operator (?) checks for null and undefined.

Comment: Yes I Initialized it in my Module like this, but the problem is that when my app-component loaded and tried to get data from my Firebase db, Firebase is not still initialized

Comment: Your AppComponent can not be loaded before your module is loaded. Are you sure, that you initialize AngularFire inside of your Module-Declaration? The "this"-keywords irritates me in your snippet

Comment: I edit my question and add my app.module.ts. It's look like yours.

Comment: Look when i try to get my user uid,email and etc whitout 
    `setTImeout()` 
I get error 
_TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of null_

And when I do it with function setTimeout with 2sec i get result

Comment: aaaaah, can you provide your html and your db access?

Comment: my main html or my app.component.html

Comment: I cannot find AuthInfo module. I only find UserInfo. Can I use it?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was my own class. UserInfo is correct

Comment: Now is working there is a little error in your answer. You need to get from this.userService.authInfo now authInfo$. authInfo$. is not necessary